# Problem on creating vala bindings (vapi) for libui

Tags: vala, vapi

I'm trying to write a VAPI file to use libui (https://github.com/andlabs/libui) in Vala.
This is my first try:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "ui.h")]
namespace LibUi {

[CCode (cname = "uiInitOptions", cprefix = "ui", has_type_id = false)]
public struct uiInitOptions {
    size_t Size;
}

[CCode (cname = "uiInit", has_type_id = false)]
public char uiInit(uiInitOptions options);
[CCode (cname = "uiMain", has_type_id = false)]
public void uiMain();
[CCode (cname = "uiQuit", has_type_id = false)]
public void uiQuit();
}
```

And this is a test code in vala:

```
using LibUi;

public static int main (string[] args) {
uiInitOptions o = uiInitOptions();
uiInit(o);
return 0;
}
```

Compiling with "valac --vapidir . --pkg libui main.vala"
brings this error:
main.vala.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `uiInit'

In the example C code of libui is this:

```
int main(void)
{
uiInitOptions o;
const char *err;
memset(&o, 0, sizeof (uiInitOptions));
err = uiInit(&o);
...
}
```

How do i make this memset stuff in vala or build it into the vapi file?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are asking a question for at least two problems at the same time here. Please ask only one question for every problem in the future. It helps to keep the site better organized.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question on the undefined references:

libui does not provide a libui.pc file for pkg-config as far as I can see. You therefore have to tell the vala compiler to link the libui.so library like this:

```
valac --vapidir . --pkg libui -X -lui main.vala
```

Now for the second question regarding memset:

You don't have to zero the memory, valac does this automatically anyway. You can see that in the generated code that you can get with:

```
valac --vapidir . --pkg libui -C main.vala
```

There is a memset there:

```
gint _vala_main (gchar** args, int args_length1) {
    gint result = 0;
    uiInitOptions o = {0};
    uiInitOptions _tmp0_;
    memset (&o, 0, sizeof (uiInitOptions));
    _tmp0_ = o;
    uiInit (&_tmp0_);
    result = 0;
    return result;
}
```

PS: You might want to get rid of the ui* prefixes in your vapi file and use a namespace instead.